# Javafx threading issue

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, fxml

I am new to Java, and  I've been working on a simple GPS radar program and I am using Javafx for the interface with FXML. I've noticed that it was crashing the interface when I have infinite loops that wait for an interrupt event. Thus I decided to separate my program to run on two threads.

The issue is that the new thread that I start from a button (Refresh) event does not see the current state of the global variables because they're not static. But FXML does not let me declare static variables . So how can I allow my background thread to see those variables of the first thread without making them static?

Here is my controller class:

```
public class Controller extends Task<Void> {
@FXML
private  ListView<String> listView;

private   String itemSelectedFromList;
@FXML
private    Circle NorthCircle;
@FXML
private  Circle SouthCircle;
@FXML
private   Circle EastCircle;
@FXML
private   Circle WestCircle;
@FXML
 private   Circle NorthWestCircle;
@FXML
private   Circle NorthEastCircle;
@FXML
private  Circle SouthWestCircle;
@FXML
private  Circle SouthEastCircle;
@FXML
private  Label bearingLabel;
@FXML
private  Label distanceLabel;   
@FXML
private Button refresher;
private float angle;
private double distance;
Thread thread;
public void readFileClicked(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {

    String[][] csvCoords = Util.getCoordsFromLocalFile();
    ObservableList<String> items = Util.getObservableList(csvCoords);
    listView.setItems(items);


}


public  void refresh(ActionEvent event) throws Exception {              
    if (listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem() == null) {
        AlertBox.display("No coords are selected",
                "Please select a coord from the list, before attempting to refresh");}
    else{
        setToDone();
        Task<Void> task = new Controller();
         thread = new Thread(task);
        if(thread.isAlive()){
            thread.interrupt();
        }






    thread.setDaemon(true);

    thread.start();


    System.out.println("Thread started");
    }
}
@Override
protected Void call() throws Exception {


    Coord destination = new Coord();
    String selection = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
    destination = Util.getCoordsFromList(selection);




    updateInterface(destination);
    return null;
}
/* Update the interface by calculating haversine, and bearing
 * 
 */
private void updateInterface(Coord destination)
        throws InterruptedException {
        double x2 = Math.toRadians(41.1);
        double y2 = Math.toRadians(-122.1716800);

        Coord source = new Coord();
        source.setX(x2);
        source.setY(y2);

        while(!thread.isInterrupted()){




        //source= ReadPort.parseData();
        distance = Util.haversine(source.getX(), source.getY(), destination.getX(), destination.getY());            
        angle = Util.getAngle(source.getX(), source.getY(), destination.getX(), destination.getY());
        updateCircles(angle);
        updateTexts(angle, distance);



        }
}



public  void updateCircles(float angle) {

    NorthCircle.setFill(Color.RED);
    SouthCircle.setFill(Color.RED);

    EastCircle.setFill(Color.RED);
    WestCircle.setFill(Color.RED);
    NorthEastCircle.setFill(Color.RED);
    NorthWestCircle.setFill(Color.RED);
    SouthEastCircle.setFill(Color.RED);
    SouthWestCircle.setFill(Color.RED);

    if (angle >= 22.5 && angle < 67.5) {
        System.out.println("Head North-East");
        NorthEastCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (angle >= 67.5 && angle < 112.5) {
        System.out.println("Head East");
        EastCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (angle >= 112.5 && angle < 157.5) {
        System.out.println("Head South-East");
        SouthEastCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (angle >= 157.5 && angle < 202.5) {
        System.out.println("South");
        SouthCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (angle >= 202.5 && angle < 247.5) {
        System.out.println("Head South-West");
        SouthWestCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (angle >= 247.5 && angle < 292.5) {
        System.out.println("Head West");
        WestCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    } else if (angle >= 292.5 && angle <= 337.5) {
        System.out.println("Head North-West");
        NorthWestCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    } else if ((angle >= 0 && angle < 22.5) || (angle > 337.5 && angle <= 360)) {
        System.out.println("North");
        NorthCircle.setFill(Color.GREEN);
    }

}

public  void updateTexts(float angle, double distance) throws InterruptedException {
    angle = (float) Math.ceil(angle);   
    bearingLabel.setText("Bearing: " + String.valueOf(angle));

    distance = Math.ceil(distance);
    distanceLabel.setText("Distance: " + distance + " feet");

}

public void setToDone() {

    listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().replace(",", "S");

    listView.setEditable(true);

    listView.setCellFactory(TextFieldListCell.forListView());
    listView.setOnEditCommit(new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ListView.EditEvent<String> t) {
            listView.getItems().set(t.getIndex(), t.getNewValue());
            System.out.println("setOnEditCommit");
        }

    });

    listView.setOnEditCancel(new EventHandler<ListView.EditEvent<String>>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ListView.EditEvent<String> t) {
            System.out.println("setOnEditCancel");
        }
    });

}}
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking... `FXML` is not supposed to contain any variables. It is also not clear which part is running on separate thread, but your controller class looks dangerous because it is extending `Task` class, and it is probably going to access UI components from a non FX application thread.

Comment: I would start by separating your `Task` (or just a `Runnable`: I don't think you need a `Task` here) into a standalone class. It doesn't really make sense to reuse the controller class as the task/runnable. Define fields `source` and `destination` in that class. You might also consider defining a field (maybe a `BiConsumer<Double, Double>`) for performing the update (i.e. a callback). Note that changes to the UI must be performed on the FX Application Thread, using `Platform.runLater(...)`.